# Online SmartPy IDE run error:

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, testing

The error says:
exports[f] is not a function.

Not sure why when I try to run....

```
import smartpy as sp

@sp.add_test(name = "First test")
def test():
    scenario = sp.test_scenario()
    scenario.p("<h1>First Output</h1>")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a load error of the page.
You need to reload the page or turn off and on your browser, something like that.
It can come from a cache problem in the browser.

Comment: I think this is correct. Since, it started working in chrome without changing any code.